# Situation based design pattern application

Tags: design-patterns

I have come across many books and references that explain a given design pattern in detail using an example and then describe the application of the pattern.

But I often come across a situation where in I have a problem at hand and I'm in dilemma which design pattern to apply there.More than one pattern seems applicable sometimes.

Are there any good references or books which enumerate situations first and then explain how a design pattern fits in?. Perhaps that explain in steps how to short list a particular pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) indeed first shows the problem, then the proposed pattern and finally the implications.

Answer (score 1):

I always use the following approach:

1. Just make your stuff working, pick any solution that works.
2. Then think about making it more clean efficient. If that means refactoring to some pattern – great.

If you see that several patterns can do the job, look at their pros and cons. Then look at your existing code and see what qualities does it lack. Then pick a pattern which matches better.

After a while, you'll be making such decisions by instinct. But now, don't afraid to experiment and make mistakes. You can always refactor your code later.

If you're interested in refactoring techniques applied to patterns, I suggest you to glance over the book "Refactoring To Patterns".